# Get Specific <td> tag in Sharepoint List New Form jquery/javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I need to add a span element to a specific  in Sharepoint List New Form.But, how to get that specific td element using jquery ot javascript.
Anyone can help me in this?[image]

beside to  single line text field i have to append span tag.how can i get that specific td.

Comment: You want to get the value of input text box (as a td element) ?

Comment: Not to get the value of input text box .I want to get the <td> element of the above text box...

Comment: Please refer to my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

To get specific `<td>` tag in Sharepoint List New Form, Try this

```
$('h3:contains("Field Name")').closest('td').next('td')
```

**Edit based on your comment**

To append an HTML tag like span or div, do the following:

```
$('h3:contains("Field Name")').closest('td').next('td').append("<span>Test</span>");
```

Comment: within this td($('h3:contains("Field Name")').closest('td').next('td')) how to add span element?

Comment: if its an accordion UI, then the above wont work!! if i add this                   $('h3:contains("Field Name")').closest('td').next('td').append("<span>Test</span>"); ,  it will not show accordion ui at all!

Answer (score 1):

To find the `Span` element, do the following.

- Select New Form - copy the url and paste in to Google Chrome.
- Press F12 - to open developer view.  Then click on the symbol I've circled in red:

[image: Dev View]

The `span` in the above picture is of the options in a choice field.

In the picture below the `span` is of the field name:

[image: span field name]

Comment: i dont have <nobr>  tag in my accordion UI. so am stuck at how to add this?

Comment: The <nobr> is wrapped around the field name.  If you have no <nobr> that would suggest to be that you have no fields present on your form...or, having done a quick search I found this explanation which should help :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532076/why-is-the-nobr-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

To append span element to td using jQuery:

```
var spanTag = "<span></span>";
$('h3:contains("Field Name")').closest('td').next('td').append(spanTag);
```